# Unable to connect to the Interent on VMware - Kali Linux 2017.2

Tags: networking, kali-linux

Trying to ping my router or any server results in: `Network is unreachable`

I have installed Kali 2017.2 on a virtual machine using VMware WS14 on a Windows 7 machine. 
The host is connected with an Ethernet cable to the router.

I ran some basic commands:

```
# vi /etc/resolv.conf
domain localdomain
nameserver 192.168.5.3

# vi /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# netstat -nr returns an empty routing table
```

Network Adapter is NAT

Comment: It would be great if some points to be provided before the negative vote

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you say you are a newbie, and Kali Linux is not recommended for newbies. It's not a general purpose distribution.

Comment: Well you got to start from somewhere, right? anyway I already used Ubuntu, Raspbian on my Raspberry pi but I still consider myself a noob.

Comment: I'm sorry but why my question is on hold? I think my description was very clear, I was unable to ping any computer/server/machine, it always resulted in 'Network is unreachable' error.

Comment: Kali is *not* the [place to start](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux). Even if you were proficient at other kinds of Linux, it's still only recommended for "professional penetration testers and security specialists". The question was put on hold because it's not detailed enough. There is not enough information for us to answer it. You might add more information if you would like it to be reopened, but since you already have the answer, it's probably not worth your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a night of struggling with this issue, I found that I had to change the Network Adapter from NAT to Bridged and it worked!

Comment: Did work for me ! 
I tried the configurations possible NAT , Bridged, Custom . . . still have the same problem